# Custom geometry created with SceneBuilder has low render priority in AggregatedView

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Custom geometry disappears on every camera movement (zoom or rotation) for about one second, then reappears again when added to an aggregated view in combination with a large model.

While the geometry is invisible I can see that there is some re-rendering of the large model going on.

Overlays (meshes rendered directly into threejs) obviously don't show this behavior.

I'm using viewer version 7.86 and the sample code from here: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer

```
modelBuilder.addFragment(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial, sphereTransform);
```

Is there any way I can prioritize rendering of my custom geometry/model?

Comment: If I understood your goal correctly, you want to add the custom geometry without any model loaded, is that right?

If you intend to load an "empty scene" you can do something similar to what was done in [this blog](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/simulate-empty-view-forge-viewer).

Comment: Hi @JoãoMartins. Thanks for your response. The "empty scene" blog post is interesting but I have a different problem. I want to render additional geometry in the viewer next to a model. Unfortunately my custom geometry seems to have the lowest possible priority when rendering and therefore disappears until the main model is fully re-rendered (on every camera move).